# Object not callable in python class in flask application

Tags: python, adafruit-circuitpython

This is my first flask application and i tried my best to get it running. Nevertheless i stuck into one error.
I tried to create a python flask app but stuck into an error.

here is my code

flask.py

```
from test_displayclass import Bartender

class MyFlask:
    bartender = Bartender()

    def __init__(self):
        #self.bartender = Bartender()
        self.bartender.test()

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

my_flask = MyFlask()

@app.route("/Test")
def Test():
    return my_flask.test.APIfunction

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=9999)
```

test_displayclass.py

```
import adafruit_ssd1306
import busio
from board import SCL, SDA
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

class Display():
    def __init__(self):
        i2c = busio.I2C(SCL, SDA)
        self.oled = adafruit_ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(128, 64, i2c, addr=0x3C)
        self.oled.fill(0)
        self.oled.show()

    def drawImage(self, image):
        self.oled(image)
        self.oled.show()


class Bartender():
     
    def __init__(self):
        self.oled = Display()


    def test(self):
        image = Image.new("1", (20, 20))
        
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        font  = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf", 25)
        self.len = len("e")
        
        draw.text(
                (0, 40 - 2 // 2),
                "e",
                font=font,
                fill=255,
            )
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Smart-Bartender/bartender_flask_new_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    my_flask = MyFlask()
  File "/home/pi/Smart-Bartender/bartender_flask_new_test.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.bartender.test()
  File "/home/pi/Smart-Bartender/test_displayclass.py", line 61, in test
    self.oled.drawImage(image)
  File "/home/pi/Smart-Bartender/test_displayclass.py", line 33, in drawImage
    self.oled(image)
TypeError: 'SSD1306_I2C' object is not callable
```

Can you advice me how to do it the correct waY?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full error traceback, not just the last line

Comment: It's done @ mousetail

Comment: Seems `self.oled` is not a function but a object. You may have meant to call a method on the object instead.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: The documentation should list the available methods on every type

Comment: Did you mean to type `self.oled.image(image)` instead of `self.oled(image)`

Answer (score 0):

Need of taken the function self.oled.image(image)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).